# Encoding problem with mount_smbfs

Tags: big-sur, mount, smb, encoding

For development with Visual Studio Code with a remote Docker devcontainer, I have a Samba share mounted on my Mac. In the Finder and the terminal I see all characters correctly displayed.

But when I call `git status` in the project's directory, I get all files listed as new files, which contain non ASCII chars (e.g. german umlauts ä,ö,ü,...).

Obviously `mount -t smbfs //host/share /some/folder` mounts the filesystem with a not UTF8 charset.

But git expects it to be in UTF8 and gives wrong results.

I can't find any possibility to tell mount_smbfs which charset to use. There is no way to configure it in */etc/nsmb.conf*, nor in in ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf. But also the `mount` and `mount_smbfs` have no option to configure the charset.

Is there really now way to solve this?

Comment: If both Finder and Terminal see the umlauts correctly, it might rather be a `git` issue.

Comment: @nohillside: no, I don't think so. I checkout out the project on ubuntu. on a mac os terminal over the smb share I have the problems. on a terminal in a docker container with a mount directly from the ubuntu host everything is fine.
I am pretty sure it's smb share related.

Comment: @nohillside: just to confirm my impression it had been a Samba mount issue: I switched over to NFS exports and git has no problems anymore. It definitely had been a Samba mount encoding issue.